# sumar cantidades por códigos mediante varios arreglos JSON

Tags: php, array, json

Buenas disculpen si mi título no es muy expresivo o correcto pero la cuestión es que no se cómo describir mi problema, el asunto es que un una base de datos donde guarde unos JSON que son de productos que no están disponibles , lo que quiero hacer es una tabla que me muestre la descripción de los productos y me sume las cantidades pero sin repetir los productos ejemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PedidosAlmacen WHERE ProductosRechazados is not null  AND ParaAlmacenID = '$ID_almacen' ORDER BY Fecha ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$productos=json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados'],true);
 foreach ($productos as $producto) {
 $codigo=$producto["codigo"];
 $Codigos[] = $producto["codigo"];
 $Codigos_result = array_unique($Codigos);
 }   
}

// esta es la nueva forma en la que traigo los productos: 
$productos = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$productos[] = json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados']) ;
 }                                                          
var_dump($productos);
```

esto es lo que me arroja $productos :

array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "560" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "30" ["descripcion"]=> string(25) "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "559" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "30" ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA" } } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "560" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "30" ["descripcion"]=> string(25) "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "559" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "30" ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA" } } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "9109" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "10" ["descripcion"]=> string(16) "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "9110" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> string(2) "10" ["descripcion"]=> string(16) "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ" } } }

hasta aquí ya sé que tengo dos productos con los códigos 1004,1005 (los codigos de los productos van del 1 al 4590) dentro de mi array `$Codigos_result` pero quiero obtener también las cantidades totales de cada uno de los productos que serían 70 de cada uno, en mi consulta estoy recibiendo 3 filas con cantidades diferentes .

**asi lucen mis JSON:[{"id": "9109", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE"}, {"id": "9110", "codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"}]**

hay mas detalles dentó del JSON como descripción y id también me gustaría mostrarlos para después haces un foreach y mostrar eso en una tabla:

```
foreach ($Codigos_result as $code){

echo "<tr>";
                                
echo "<td>" . $code['id'] . "</td>";
    
echo "<td>" . $code["codigo"] . "</td>";
    
echo "<td>" . $code["descripcion"] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $code["cantidad"] . "</td>";
    
echo "<td>" . $code['PedidoDeSucursal'] . "</td>";
    
echo "</tr> ";

}


echo " </tbody>";

echo " </table>";
```

espero haber dado a entender de forma correcta mi duda ya que no sé cómo resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuminedo que tienes un  json de la siguiente manera:

```
$result = json_decode(
    '[{
        "id": "9109",
        "codigo": "1004",
        "cantidad": "10",
        "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE"
    },{
        "id": "9110",
        "codigo": "1005",
        "cantidad": "10",
        "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"
    },{
        "id": "9110",
        "codigo": "1005",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"
    }]'
);
```

Donde el "id" puede estar repetido. Entonces:

```
$respuesta = [];

foreach ($result as $k => $fila) {
    if(!array_key_exists($fila->id,$respuesta)){
        $respuesta[$fila->id]= [
           "id"=> $fila->id,
           "codigo"=> $fila->codigo,
           "cantidad"=> (int)$fila->cantidad,
           "descripcion"=> $fila->descripcion
        ];
    }else{
        $respuesta[$fila->id]["cantidad"] += $fila->cantidad;
    }
}

var_dump($respuesta);
```

Basicamente lo que haces es crear un array `$respuesta` donde vas almacenando los elementos diferentes del `json` identificandolos por el campo `id` si se repite se suma la cantidad.

resultado:

```
array (size=2)
  9109 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '9109' (length=4)
      'codigo' => string '1004' (length=4)
      'cantidad' => int 10
      'descripcion' => string '3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE' (length=16)
  9110 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '9110' (length=4)
      'codigo' => string '1005' (length=4)
      'cantidad' => int 11
      'descripcion' => string '3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ' (length=16)
```

Comment: la forma en la que recibo los json es asi ```$productos=json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados'],true);``` creo que tiene algo que ver con que en el resultado del foreach todo me salga null

Comment: quita el `true` y  listo

Comment: ya lo hice pero sigue sin funcionar , pero php me arroja estos errores **Trying to get property 'codigo' of non-object** pero no solo con código sino también con id y descripción , creo que tiene que ver con el  ```mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)```

Comment: puedes agregar la siguiente linea `var_dump($productos);`  despues de la linea  `$productos=json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados'],true);`  y   mostrarme que imprime

Comment: edite el código de mi pregunta para que veas los cambios que hice con respecto a lo que me comentas