# sumar cantidades de un array dependiendo de los elementos de un JSON

Tags: php, array, json

Buenas anteriormente realice una pregunta que me genero esta respuesta ya la adapte a mi códigos para que funciones solo que no logo hacer que se sumen las cantidades de los productos con los códigos iguales este es el código respuesta de mi pregunta anterior ya hice las modificaciones que eran necesarias para que funcionara en mi código pero no suma las cantidades :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$productos=json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados'],true);
$respuesta = [];                              
foreach ($productos as $k => $fila) {

  if(!array_key_exists($fila['codigo'],$respuesta)){
   $respuesta[$fila['codigo']]= [
   "codigo"=> $fila['codigo'],
   "cantidad"=> (int)$fila['cantidad'],
   "descripcion"=> $fila['descripcion']
  ];
 }else{
 $respuesta[$fila['codigo']]["cantidad"] += $fila['cantidad'];
   }
 }
                                   
var_dump($respuesta);

}
```

eso es lo que me arroja el **var_dump** :
`array(2) { [1005]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> int(30) ["descripcion"]=> string(25) "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE" } [1004]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> int(30) ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA" } } array(2) { [1005]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> int(30) ["descripcion"]=> string(25) "3 EN 1 HW MATE 20 LITE NE" } [1004]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> int(30) ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA" } } array(2) { [1004]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1004" ["cantidad"]=> int(10) ["descripcion"]=> string(16) "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE" } [1005]=> array(3) { ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1005" ["cantidad"]=> int(10) ["descripcion"]=> string(16) "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ" } }`

esperaba recibir algo como :
`[{"codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "70", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE"}, {"codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "70", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"}]`

[esta fue mi pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/573539/sumar-cantidades-por-c%C3%B3digos-mediante-varios-arreglos-json/573549#573549)

Comment: Prueba convirtiendo a enterro con la funcion [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php)

Comment: Pero, siendo que los datos vienen de una base de datos, ¿por qué no sumarlos en la instrucción SQL directamente? No es buena idea manipular un conjunto de datos a posteriori.

Comment: @A.Cedano como debería ser mi SQL para sumar las cantidades de códigos iguales ? la que estoy utilizando solo me arroja todo y después pensaba que podía manipular los datos dado a que guardo las listas de productos en JSON en mi base de datos: ```"SELECT * FROM PedidosAlmacen WHERE ProductosRechazados is not null  AND ParaAlmacenID = '$ID_almacen' ORDER BY Fecha ASC"```

Comment: Pues sería con un `SELECT SUM(laColumnaConElValorASumar) FROM laTabla WHERE ... GROUP BY laColumnaConIDUnico`

Comment: @A.Cedano pero como me refiero a que 'mi columna con el valor a sumar' es un JSON  esto es lo que tengo en mi columna de la base de datos ```[{"id": "9109", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 NE"}, {"id": "9110", "codigo": "1005", "cantidad": "10", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 HW Y60 RJ"}]``` tengo tres de estos como SUM se supone que me va sumar las cantidades de acuerdo a los códigos

Comment: Pero a ver, tienes guardado todo eso en una columna ¿? ¿Acaso no has diseñado una tabla con columnas por separado: `id, codigo, cantidad` etc?

Comment: no , ya que maneja un montón de listas de json y no creo que crear una tabla para cada situación que se haga el guardado de los json sea útil, por eso mi intención de manipular el json trayéndolo

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres sumar los elementos dentro de tu json, lo que tienes que haces transformar ese json con json_decode(), asi puedes acceder a los datos y puedes hacer lo que deseas, caso contrario no puedes porque es un texto como tal.

Comment: ya utilizo uno , lo estoy empleando mal ?```$productos=json_decode($row['ProductosRechazados'],true);```

Comment: Pasame todo el resultado de tu consulta porfa

Comment: es muy extenso creo que no puedo ponerlo por cometario deja edito la pregunta